# Node/express - How to force HTTPS without being blocked by CORS

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, https

I am developing a MEAN stack based web app, using Cloud9 and Heroku. I want all users to be forced to use HTTPS, and I found a nice way using Express middleware:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next) {
    if(req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"] == "http") {
      console.log("HTTP call detected, not allowed);
      return res.redirect('https://' + req.hostname + req.path);
    } else {
      console.log("HTTPs call detected, allowed");
        return next();
    }
```

I hope this can work for all GET, POST, PUT, DELETE requests I receive, thinking that any call to HTTP should just be redirected to the identical, corresponding HTTPS request.

Now while this in itself seems to work, I am getting the CORS policy error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://myappurlhere.herokuapp.com/app. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://myappurlhere.herokuapp.com' is
>   therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Now I do understand the concept that this is the standard CORS policy that prevents cross-domain requests, but I am not exactly sure how I should approach this. I thought this would go as a same-domain-request, but apparently not.

I have seen that some people argue that a second server should run and catch HTTP traffic, redirecting, but I am only using one server. I don't understand why that couldn't work.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
function requireHTTPS(req, res, next) {
   if (!req.secure) {
          return res.redirect('https://' + req.get('host') + req.url);
    }
        next();
}
app.use(requireHTTPS);
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I made HTTPS traffic forced now, but I don't think I solved the actual problem. What I am now using is this:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=8640000; includeSubDomains');
    if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] && req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === "http") {
      return res.redirect(301, 'https://' + req.host + req.url);
    } else {
      console.log("HTTPS call detected");
      return next();
    }
});
```

It seems that this effectively forces strict TLS, probably because of the header change. However, this also mean that the redirect never seems to happen - the test for "http" is always false. Hence, the problem with COTS redirect policy remains.

This is where I would really like some input - should I add some policies allowing cross domain requests? That sounds insecure, and why? I am on the same domain, I just want HTTPS.

Any input appreciated.